# R difference between cor and cor.test

Tags: r

I do not understand why the function cor and cor.test does not give me the same result with pearson methode!

```
> cor(varCor,method="pearson")
              Distributeurs Importateurs Producteurs Préparateurs
Distributeurs     1.0000000    0.5480281   0.2357191    0.7115063
Importateurs      0.5480281    1.0000000  -0.2318366    0.1740853
Producteurs       0.2357191   -0.2318366   1.0000000    0.4414107
Préparateurs      0.7115063    0.1740853   0.4414107    1.0000000

> cor.test(annee2010$Distributeurs,annee2010$Préparateurs, method="pearson")

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  annee2010$Distributeurs and annee2010$Préparateurs
t = 14.6233, df = 94, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7599547 0.8859092
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.8334552
```

it comes from my data or a difference that I did not understand help?

Comment: what is `varCor`?  Is it the exact same two vectors `annee2010$Distributeurs` and `annee2010$Préparateurs`?

Comment: Could you edit your question to give us the output of `dput(varCor)` and `dput(annee2010)`, perhaps edited for length?

Answer (score 1):

you're right ! It come from my data!
varCor is a na.omit(annee2010) ... So it changes the result when I work on the same data.frame...

```
cor.test(varCor$Distributeurs,varCor$Préparateurs, method="pearson")

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  varCor$Distributeurs and varCor$Préparateurs
t = 4.5283, df = 20, p-value = 0.0002048
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4141262 0.8716421
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.7115063
```

thank's !!

Answer (score 1):

cor() and cor.test() **are** compatible.
I guess your `varCor` is already a variance-covariance matrix on which you call `cor()` again?
If you have a variance-covariance matrix, and want the correlations from that,
do use
   `cov2cor()`
on the vcov matrix.

See ?cov2cor
(and look at the code of `cov2cor`.  One of the reason I had added this function to R, is to show
*how* you can compute this in a way that is both efficient and easy to understand.
..
the latter even more if you look at the real source code of R, or that function respectively, as there you can see the **comments** in the R code.
Online, this would be at the bottom of
   https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/cor.R

Comment: in fact non varCor is juste a data frame with numeric colonne and na.omit, but thank's for the precision